# Using a Python Script Input parameter as an output

Tags: python, modelbuilder, python-script-tool, parameters

I have a Python script that takes several input parameters, one of which is the name of an output folder which will hold processed data (outFolder). I want to be able to access that outFolder variable displayed as an output (outFolder--> Process-->outFolder) as well once the process has finished and "outputted" the results into the outFolder. Basically, I want to use that same filled outFolder as an input for another process in ModelBuilder. How do I do this?

```
#Get the input feature class, optional fields and the output filename
input_FC = sys.argv[1]
inField = sys.argv[2]
theFName = sys.argv[3]
outFolder = sys.argv[4]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Use arcpy.setParameterAsText and set it equal to your input variable. Then add a parameter to your script tool. Make it an output or derived type. It will then let you connect as long as the data type is compatible with the next tool input type

Comment: What should I use in the "text" parameter for arcpy.SetParameterAsText(index, text)?

Comment: OK, this worked. I removed all of the sys.argv methods on my main parameters and used `arcpy.GetParameterAsText` instead. Using both methods in the same script created too much confusion in the indexing. Once I started with an index of (0) and added `outFolder` as my "text" parameter. everything worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use arcpy.setParameterAsText and set the outval equal to your input variable.
Then add a parameter to your script tool. Make it an output or derived type.

The index # of the output parameter in the script tool is what you enter in the arcpy.setParameterAsText(#,outval)

It will then let you connect as long as the data type is compatible with the next tool input type